# MS teams makes the whole GUI stall: GpuWatchdog segfault

Tags: debian, gpu, segmentation-fault, nouveau, microsoft-teams

Since I use microsoft teams on my Debian buster machine, I get a GUI freeze sometimes: The mouse pointer can still be moved on the screen, but no visible feedback on clicks or keyboard presses. Also no switching to a console with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

I could not help myself other then `ssh`ing to the machine to restart `Xorg`.

The `dmesg` shows me fingerprints of `teams`, but I guess the deeper problem must the in the `nouveau` GPU driver?

```
[ 4918.083079] show_signal_msg: 7 callbacks suppressed
[ 4918.083082] GpuWatchdog[2056]: segfault at 0 ip 000055dcd609b006 sp 00007f5a8f043490 error 6 in teams[55dcd2705000+5fbe000]
[ 4918.083087] Code: 89 de e8 4d 0e 71 ff 80 7d cf 00 79 09 48 8b 7d b8 e8 1e 45 ce fe 41 8b 84 24 e0 00 00 00 89 45 b8 48 8d 7d b8 e8 ea f0 66 fc <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 37 13 00 00 48 83 c4 38 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e
[ 5006.078739] traps: Watchdog[2423] trap invalid opcode ip:555c23f287de sp:7f77fb7fd6f0 error:0 in teams[555c23dba000+5fbe000]
```

For now I deactivated GPU acceleration in MS teams, but would you recommend switching to NVIDIA driver instead of `nouveau` in this case?

Comment: Seeing this in Fedora 34 (5.13.9-200) too with Intel HD Graphics driver recently. Very annoying - whole desktop freezes.

My recovery sequence is to press the power suspend button the the laptop. The system suspends after a few mins, and them will resume, which is less disruptive than a power reset.

Comment: Did the answer below fix this for you?

Comment: Kind of.  After the next dist-upgrade, I switched away from nouveau and got rid of that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nouveau` is known for being quite unstable and crash-prone, so I'd recommend installing NVIDIA proprietary drivers instead.

The error you're getting indicates exactly that.

Alternatively try installing a fresh kernel, 4.19 is quite dated and may not contain all the fixes the nouveau driver has seen.